# Asynchronous connection

Tags: c#, asynchronous

In c#,I am using the following code:

```
IPAddress localaddress=IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
```

to get a System.Net.IPAddress instance which am using in:

```
IPEndPoint ip= new IPEndPoint(localaddress,5555);
```

I am however getting an error saying:

```
A field initializer cannot reference the nonstatic field, method, or property 'WindowsApplication1.lanmessenger.localaddress'   .
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing your code looks like this:

```
public class lanmessenger {
  IPAddress localaddress=IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
  IPEndPoint ip= new IPEndPoint(localaddress,5555);

  public lanmessenger(){
  ...
  }
}
```

The problem here is that the compiler doesn't want you using initialized fields the way you are. You're using `localaddress` to initialize `ip`, which is problematic from the compiler's prospective. Two ways to get around this:

Inline it:

```
 IPEndPoint ip= new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");,5555);
```

Or just do it in the constructor: (generally better)

```
public class lanmessenger {
  IPAddress localaddress;
  IPEndPoint ip;

  public lanmessenger(){
    this.localaddress = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1")
    this.ip = new IPEndPoint(localaddress,5555);
  }
}
```

Comment: yeah i inferred that..Used the first alternative and its working.
Thanks a lot.